# Arrange 18 pips on a die with at least one 0 side to maximize the probability that 5 rolls sum to 13 or more.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

You are arranging pips on a standard 6-sided dice.

Rules:

- At least one side must be left blank at 0.
- The average roll must be 3 (so, you have 18 pips to distribute among five sides).
- You want to maximize the probability that the sum of 5 rolls equals or exceeds 13.

What's your best strategy?

Bonus for extending to 4 or 6 rolls, etc. or generalizing some intuition somehow.

(This question was inspired by Pandemic: The Cure.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the average is more than enough, one might expect that the optimum is achieved by minimising the variance, which is achieved by distributing the pips as evenly as possible, $4,4,4,3,3$. The probability of rolling at least $13$ is then the probability of rolling at least $4$ non-zeros minus the probability of rolling one zero and four threes:

$$
6^{-5}\left(\binom555^5+\binom545^4-\binom542^4\right)=\frac{3085}{3888}\approx79\%\;.
$$

[Here's code](https://gist.github.com/joriki/02b6d95402ebc825c94fd340b0c8d310) that checks that this is indeed the optimum.